# Is there a way to emulate an Xbox controller?

Tags: macos, keyboard, software-recommendation, mouse

I've downloaded [Onecast](https://onecast.me/) which allows me to stream an Xbox One to my Mac and it supports connecting an Xbox controller. Is there a way to emulate an Xbox controller with my keyboard and mouse on my Mac so I can use it in games?

I am using macOS Mojave. I would prefer to use an application that is under $10.

Comment: It may be worth adding the version of macOS you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no way to do this natively, I've had to run a VM with [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/)(VirtualBox is too slow). I could then use the Windows Xbox app and [XboxKeyboardMouse](https://github.com/fqlx/XboxKeyboardMouse).

Answer (score 3):

I haven’t used these to emulate an XBox One controller, but I have used these to emulate a whole range of others:

- [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html)
- [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/)

I’d start with USB Overdrive as it offers a much simpler interface. ControllerMate provides a lot of advanced functionality, but can take quite some time to suss out.

Comment: How would I go about configuring USB Overdrive to emulate another device? I can only see options for binding a button to a certain set of actions.

Comment: Hmm, it's actually been years since I've used either package and I don't recall my steps. If I get a chance I'll reinstall USB Overdrive and see if and how it's possible to do. Sorry I can't offer any clear direction at this stage. :(